# meaning and using of the terms "eye toilet", "ear toilet" and "oral cavity toilet"

Tags: word-usage

Is it in common use to refer the secretions of the eye, ear, and oral cavity - as a "**toilet**"?

I got a text with the following terms:

> "Techniques  of eye **toilet**, ear **toilet** and oral cavity **toilet** of a
>   baby"

As I understand the meaning of them is secretions of the eyes, ears, and mouth (saliva?). Isn't it?

Indeed, by googling I found some professional books which uses this terms, but I'm not sure how it sounds like to the ears of the English native speaker. When I met it first as ELL it sounded weird.

links:

[Government of western Australia- eye toilet - guide](http://www.kemh.health.wa.gov.au/development/manuals/O&G_guidelines/sectionb/10/b10.5.1.1.pdf)  (PDF)

[Government of western Australia- ear toilet - guide](http://pmh.health.wa.gov.au/general/CACH/docs/manual/6%20Procedures/6.4/6.4.1%20Irrigation%20ear%20toilet.pdf) (PDF)

Comment: As an east coast, American-English speaker, this would be [my first time](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Intensive_Care_Nursing/Essential_Nursing_Cares_(eye)) hearing of it. Shows how much I know :D.

Comment: I've been in and around hospitals for decades, and I have never heard this usage before.

Comment: Heh, yes, I had just been able to mention the definition for which JavaLatte just posted an answer. If you see [here](https://www.google.com.tw/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-ab&q=toilet+definition&oq=toilet+definition&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i10k1j0l2j0i10k1l2j0i22i30k1l4.2729.4037.0.4219.11.11.0.0.0.0.164.837.8j2.10.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.10.828...0i67k1.G_MynmFCsRo), it even specifically mentions "as a medical procedure." I would even almost say that I've heard it in British television.

Comment: Maybe you know common alternative for these terms? it would be better if they're common in use in professional books.

Answer (score 4):

A rather old fashioned meaning of [toilet](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/toilet) is  **the process of washing and dressing yourself**.

I venture to suggest that the word **toilet** in this context means washing the eyes, ears and mouth.

Comment: Thank you. What about the meaning of cleaning for the word toilet in this context?

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent  Sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you provide an example sentence?

Comment: Sorry. I meant to ask if I can say that the meaning of the word toilet can be "cleaning" in the context that I'm talking about. I put links in the question.

Comment: http://www.dia.org/object-info/618760c1-fffa-4b4b-8aae-9cc1ec600832.aspx?position=252

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent: yes, you can.

Comment: @Tromano I don't understand what you meant to say about the link.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent: The title of TRomano's painting is "A lady at her toilet". That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use it in this context to mean "Cleaning".
Most people don't use the word "toilet" as a substitute for cleaning in every day language.